# Star Wars Set Identification, small sets with Snow Troopers

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Please help if possible to identify this Star Wars set. Let me know if you need any other information.

[image: Two bags from apparent Star Wars set]

Answer (score 7):

Definitely [8084 - LegoSnowtrooper Battle Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8084-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D):

[image]

There are only 4 Star Wars sets with the [white tricycle body](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30187b&in=S), and you can clearly see all the other parts match.